# Woocommerce create variable product multiple attributes programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating woocommerce variable product programmatically. Successfully created single attribute(size) but now i am trying to create another attribute (color). I have this attributes array from my form.

```
Array
(
    [0] => size
    [1] => color
)
```

and here is the code i tried :

```
       $args_t = array(
                'orderby' => 'name',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'hide_empty' => true,
                'fields' => 'names'
            );

        if ($product_attributes) {
            foreach ($product_attributes as $attr) {
                $avail_attributes = array();
                $avail_attributes = get_terms(wc_attribute_taxonomy_name($attr), $args_t);
                $attr = 'pa_'.$attr;
                wp_set_object_terms($new_product_id, $avail_attributes, $attr);
                $thedata = array();
                $thedata = Array($attr => Array(
                        'name' => $attr,
                        'value' => '',
                        'postion' => '0',
                        'is_visible' => '1',
                        'is_variation' => '1',
                        'is_taxonomy' => '1'
                ));
                update_post_meta($new_product_id, '_product_attributes', $thedata);
            }
        }
```

Here is the screenshot of current situation:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are problems in your code.. the obvious one is that you are updating the post meta inside the foreach loop. Making it overwriting the current value until the last one. Please try the code below.

```
    if ($product_attributes) {
        $thedata = array();
        foreach ($product_attributes as $attr) {
            $avail_attributes = array();
            $avail_attributes = get_terms(wc_attribute_taxonomy_name($attr), $args_t);
            $attr = 'pa_'.$attr;
            wp_set_object_terms($new_product_id, $avail_attributes, $attr);
            $thedata[sanitize_title($attr)] = Array(
                    'name' => wc_clean($attr),
                    'value' => '',
                    'postion' => '0',
                    'is_visible' => '1',
                    'is_variation' => '1',
                    'is_taxonomy' => '1'
            );
        }
        update_post_meta($new_product_id, '_product_attributes', $thedata);
    }
```